# RecyclerView last items are not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I don't know what is exact issue but my recycleview is not showing last two item
"Item 49" and "Item 50". i tried multiple thing but couldn't able to solve this.

here if you see last two items item 49 and item 50 is not visible

[image]

I want to show all my 50 items when scroll to down but only 48 items are showing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sheetBehaviour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="462dp"

            >
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycleview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:itemCount="50"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/layout_items"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
My adapter class 

package com.example.recycleviewissue

import android.R
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class MyListAdapter(listdata: MutableList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    private val listdata: MutableList<String>

    // RecyclerView recyclerView;
    init {
        this.listdata = listdata
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val listItem: View =
            layoutInflater.inflate(com.example.recycleviewissue.R.layout.layout_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.textView.setText(listdata[position])

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listdata.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var textView: TextView

        init {
            textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(com.example.recycleviewissue.R.id.items) as TextView
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var recycleView : RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycleView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        val listOfItem = mutableListOf<String>()
        for(i in 1..50){
            listOfItem.add("Item "+i)
        }
        val adapter : MyListAdapter = MyListAdapter(listOfItem)
        recycleView.adapter = adapter

        val sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.sheetBehaviour));
        sheetBehavior.isDraggable = false
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQd2q.png)

Comment: You probably aren't returning a correct size in the overriden method. Show the code

Comment: @cmak please check i have added adapter class and mainactivity class code

Comment: @JonR85 Why would you do that?  That's never a good idea.

Comment: Item 49 is definitely visible in your screenshot, it's just covered by whatever that blue thing is.

Comment: @RyanM please check the new image that was old one this is new screen short after removing the blue part

Comment: Pure speculation: try removing `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`; I think bottom sheets involve nested scrolling

Comment: @RyanM if i removing android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" this . if i scroll this the bottomsheet getting expanded and all 50 items are visible but i don't want bottom sheet to be get expanded

Comment: So you mean all items are loaded, just not bisible when you scroll to the bottom?

Comment: Do override getitemid

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a `CordinatorLayout`'s behavioural issue. You define the recyclerview's behaviour, but it is child of `LinearLayout`. In this case you should add another `CoordinatorLayout` within the `LinearLayout` in order to make the recyclerview's scrolling behaviour make sense.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sheetBehaviour"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="462dp" >
            
<!--             Add this coordinatorlayout -->
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" >
                
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycleview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:itemCount="50"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/layout_items"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />
                
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```